# Como manipular title="" pelo c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

É possível botar o texto do atributo title="" pelo c#?

O title que pretendo manipular é:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="linkTitle" CssClass="link_title search-result-link-title tooltip-init" Target="_top"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="título" data-original-title="título" />
```

Comment: Você que altera o texto do title="título" ou do ID="linkTitle" ?

Comment: @Amanda-Vieira você precisa ser mais explícita na sua dúvida.

Quer manipular antes de renderizar o title ou depois que a página foi carregada ?

Existem muitas maneiras diferentes de resolver, mas a dúvida precisa ser melhor abordada !

Comment: Olá @MaurícioJúnior desculpe não perguntar corretamente, mas você entendeu perfeitamente. O seu comentário "HyperLink1.ToolTip = "TEXTO A SER RENDERIZADO NO TITLE DO ELEMENTO A HREF!";" funcionou e era exatamente o que eu queria! Obrigada!

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza o title="". A resposta do Mauriício já me ajudou. Obrigada.

Comment: Jóia @AmandaVieira ... que bom que conseguistes! Bom trabalho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propriedade **`ToolTip`** !

```
<asp:HyperLink ToolTip="Aqui é renderizado o TITLE!">
```

Sugiro que mude o título da pergunta para ASP.NET, C# é a sintaxe usada no ASP.NET!

No Code Behind usa-se a mesma propriedade !

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HyperLink1.ToolTip = "TEXTO A SER RENDERIZADO NO TITLE DO ELEMENTO A HREF!";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Exemplo]
[image: Código]

Comment: Não entendi nada, por acaso eu falei alguma coisa?

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza Desculpe, pensei que tivesse negativado minha resposta!

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando JavaScript, faz uma requisição ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          url: '@Url.Action("SetarTitulo", "Controller")',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify({ }),
          success: function (data) {
                   title = data.Retorno.Titulo;
                   $("#linkTitle title").html(title);
          }
      });
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult SetarTitulo(){

         var titulo = "Meu titulo";

         return Json(new RetornoAjax
         {
            Retorno = new
            {
                Titulo = titulo
            }
    });
}
```